# Replicate Stata margins in R

Tags: r, replication, regression, stata, margins

I have a regression model with a bunch of indicator variables interacting with regressors. In this case P-values may work well for model selection. I know Stata has a command called `margins`, and it really helps in this case. Example:

```
margins, dydx(*)
```

From the [relevant Stata manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rmargins.pdf)

> ### Description
>
> Margins are statistics calculated from predictions of a previously fit model at fixed values of some
>   covariates and averaging or otherwise integrating over the remaining covariates.
>   The `margins` command estimates margins of responses for specified values of covariates and
>   presents the results as a table.
>   Capabilities include estimated marginal means, least-squares means, average and conditional
>   marginal and partial effects (which may be reported as derivatives or as elasticities), average and
>   conditional adjusted predictions, and predictive margins.

Is there any similar function in R?

Comment: There is no reason not to cite the latest manual edition (14, as I write).

Comment: start by checking out the `effects` and `lsmeans` packages

Answer (score 8):

I have produced an R port of Stata's margins command called - intuitively - [margins](https://cran.r-project.org/package=margins). Behavior is what you would probably expect:

```
library("margins")
x <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * hp + wt, data = mtcars)
summary(margins(x))
##  factor     AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
##     cyl  0.0381 0.5999  0.0636 0.9493 -1.1376  1.2139
##      hp -0.0463 0.0145 -3.1909 0.0014 -0.0748 -0.0179
##      wt -3.1198 0.6613 -4.7176 0.0000 -4.4160 -1.8236
```

Compared to Stata:

```
quietly reg mpg c.cyl##c.hp wt
margins, dydx(*)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         cyl |   .0381376   .5998897     0.06   0.950    -1.192735     1.26901
          hp |  -.0463187    .014516    -3.19   0.004     -.076103   -.0165343
          wt |  -3.119815    .661322    -4.72   0.000    -4.476736   -1.762894
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```